# ehcache and lucene comparison

Tags: lucene, ehcache

We are working design of new project where we need to decided framework for caching. We are looking at ehcache and lucene for caching.
We need decide whether to use lucene or ehcache for our caching requirement? What are advantage/disadvantage of using ehcache or lucene for caching?

Answer (score 5):

Lucene is primarily a search engine with minimal caching for search results. It is *incorrect* to call it a caching framework

Ehcache and OSCache are popular caching frameworks which you could use/evaluate. See [OSCache vs. EHCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97741/oscache-vs-ehcache)