# Ehcache Search and Lucene Comparison

Tags: search, lucene, indexing, distributed, ehcache

There is an existing [ehcache and lucene comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152852/ehcache-and-lucene-comparison) sometime back and the answer is they can't be compared directly. However in EhCache 2.4, it now has [search feature](http://ehcache.org/documentation/search.html). We are thinking to migrate our currently Lucene solution into EhCache Search. One of the benefit I see is when EhCache is integrated with Terracotta, it can be become distributed cache and index easily. Any other concerns I should take account before the migration? Could anyone share their experience about EhCache Search as cache and index solution?

Thanks.

**Update**: After a quick test, it seems like EhCache Search does not allow cache to be persisted into disk. I got the below error if I try to set diskPersistent="true" on my ehcache.xml. Which mean the indexed cache need to be rebuilt everytime. I see this is one of the disadvantage.

> Search attributes not supported by
>   this store type:
>   net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.impl.DiskPersistentStore

Comment: What if you use ehcache **in front** of Lucene? Let lucene do the indexing, and you can cache and distribute the results with ehcache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are list of limitation:

1. Can't persist searchable cache into disk.
2. Custom [AttributeExtractor](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/search/attribute/AttributeExtractor.html#attributeFor%28net.sf.ehcache.Element%29) only support certain types, which means you can't use search attribute with parameterize T like net.sf.ehcache.search.Attribute.eq(T), net.sf.ehcache.search.Attribute.between(T, T) etc but only net.sf.ehcache.search.Attribute.ilike(String) which may cause slower performance and less search constraint. I have to edit the EhCache source to make it support my custom type as I wish to use Attribute.eq(T).

Thanks.