# Is OSCache under development or it has been discontinued?

Tags: java, hibernate, oscache, opensymphony

Does anyone know if `OSCache` is underdevelopment or not?

I know that `OpenSymphony` is no longer under development, but some of its projects still live on ( like `Quartz` ).

I wasn't able to find anything relevant about `OSCache` that wasn't at least two years old.

So, does anyone know if the `OSCache` project is discontinued ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this answer is that OSCache is no more.

See the commenton this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367693/1348 - it mentions an annoucment from OpenSymphony [here](http://www.opensymphony.com/).

Comment: Yes, I thought as much. Thanks for confirming